# Run mutation on Route change VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So i am using Vuex and have a simple mutation set up which console logs a message. I have two routes setup, the `/`which goes to my HelloWorld component and `/another` which goes to the AnotherWorld component. I am trying to setup a `watch` on my `route` so that when the route changes, it fires off the mutation. I did setup a `watch` but it doesn't seem to be firing off my mutation.

Check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-volhard-ci46d?file=/src/router/index.js).

Check out the code snippet:-

This is My Vuex Store:-

```
  mutations: {
    routeChange() {
      console.log("Helloooo!!!!!");
    }
```

This is My Hello World Component:-

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
    <router-link to="/another">Switch</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.$store.commit("routeChange");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my AnotherWorld Component:-

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Another World</h1>
    <router-link to="/">Back</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

As you can see i have setup the watch but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a navigation guard in your router instead of getting one component to watch?

Comment: yeah i agree. i was just looking into the navigation guards, just wasn't sure. Since i am still learning about Vue and router :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead use a [global after hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks) navigation guard in your router.

For example

```js
// router.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...]
})

router.afterEach(() => {
  store.commit('routeChange')
})

export default router
```

---

If you only want to catch route navigation away from certain components, you can use the `beforeRouteLeave` [in-component guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

```js
// MyComponent.vue

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    this.$store.commit('routeChange')
    next()
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to call the mutation only after a certain route is left and not after every route change? for example in this case when `/` is left.

Comment: Thank you so much. :D. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you put watchers in individual route components they will never fire because $route is set before these components instantiation and is then changed after these components destruction.

You either need to put the watch in App.vue (parent of `<router-view>`), or commit from one of the vue-router guards (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I put in my vue-router guard.